# Where are the dlls -WebDriver.Common and WebDriver.Firefox in Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running some tests on Selenium Web Driver. But looks like that I need some dlls like WebDriver.Common.dll, WebDriver.Firefox.dll.
I had downloaded the web driver api from this link
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-dotnet-2.1.0.zip&can=2&q=
  And when I unzip, could not find the dll that I mentioned in the subject.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 & creating a class library.
Please let me know if there is another link to download the mentioned dll or another way to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDriver.Common.dll, WebDriver.Firefox.dll, and all of the other browser-specific assemblies were combined into a single WebDriver.dll assembly for the final 2.0.0 (and later) releases. You should only have to create a reference to WebDriver.dll to be able to use all of the functionality of the Selenium WebDriver API.

Answer (score 1):

Another helpful step to point out is adding the proper using statements for each driver type.

For Example:

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
```